# How to simulate multiple <br/> tag with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was spending some time on a question when I came up with a funny solution but not really finalized.

See the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Baldrani/9484wtna/8/)** and try to erase the `<br/>` tag.

The idea is too get the same effect **(red div displayed)** but without using this solution relatively horrible.

So here is my question : **How do I simulate `<br/>` tags with CSS or eventually Js ?**

Just some more difficulty : You can't touch the wrapper.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <p>Some text and descriptions</p>
    <div class="widget box-wrap">
        <div class="box"><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></div>
    </div>
    <p>Some more text and description and some more offcourse and a bit more, and just a tiny bit more</p>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.wrapper { 
    width:300px; 
    display:block; 
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:gray;
}
.widget {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    background-color:green;
}
.box {
    background-color:red;
    visibility:visible;
}

.box-wrap {
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 0;
   padding-bottom: 60%;
}
.box-wrap div {
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stretch `.box` with position absolute since it's relative to the parent. This way you can be sure that it takes entire space of the parent container.

```css
.wrapper {
    width:300px;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:gray;
}
.widget {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    background-color:graeen;
}
.box {
    background-color:red;
    visibility:visible;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    left: 0; right: 0;
}
.box-wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 60%;
}
.box-wrap div {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <p>Some text and descriptions</p>
    <div class="widget box-wrap">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <p>Some more text and description and some more offcourse and a bit more, and just a tiny bit more</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution is great too !

Answer (score 2):

Just apply the height to be 100% in `.box` and remove the `height: 0` from `.box-wrap` or you may remove all styles of `.box-wrap` which is really unnecessarily causing the problem because of `height: 0` and `overflow: hidden`:

```
.box {
    background-color:red;
    visibility:visible;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9484wtna/23/)

Comment: May be I'm not understanding your problem.

Comment: I need the red div to be displayed

Answer (score 2):

You can safely remove `<br />` and use `padding`. When the content area has a background, color, or image set on it, this will extend into the padding, which is why you can think of the padding as extending the content. For example using 'padding-top':

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: gray;
}
.widget {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
}
.box {
  background-color: red;
  visibility: visible;
  padding-top: 180px;/*add padding top*/
}
.box-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 60%;
}
.box-wrap div {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Some text and descriptions</p>
  <div class="widget box-wrap">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <p>Some more text and description and some more offcourse and a bit more, and just a tiny bit more</p>
</div>
```

**Reference**:

[Box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model)

Comment: Beautiful ! Well played :)

Comment: Glad that I helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

Use absolute positioning? It will stretch to the full height and width of the container:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: gray;
}
.widget {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
}
.box {
  background-color: red;
  visibility: visible;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.box-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 60%;
}
.box-wrap div {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Some text and descriptions</p>
  <div class="widget box-wrap">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <p>Some more text and description and some more offcourse and a bit more, and just a tiny bit more</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use just one `<br>` tag and then use `line-height` in css.

HTML:

```
<p>
Lorem ipsum <br> Another line
</p>
```

CSS:

```
p {
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: I want to erase totally the <br/>

Answer (score 0):

Use min-height in .box css like:

```
.box {
    background-color:red;
    visibility:visible;
    min-height:100px;
}
```

Comment: I cant specify the height o the box; I edit my question.

Comment: @baldrani This is the min-height, Height of div will grow automatically as and when content of div will change